# Packageinstaller session Permission denied

Tags: android, miui

I am trying to install split apks in Poco f1. When I am committing the session it is giving permission denied error. If I am turn off MIUI Optimization it is working fine else it is giving below error.

“E/PackageInstaller: Commit of session 5678435738 failed: Permission Denied”

Answer (score 0):

On MIUI you have to specifically accept the installation on phone to install from PC.
There will be a popup on your phone screen like on image attached, just check the "Remember my choice" and click on "Install"[image]

Comment: I created a split apk installer app. Where users pass any app split apks and app will install But in MIUI it is giving permission denied error.

Comment: @MohitSha its true about MIUI .. see this post https://in.c.mi.com/thread-2145537-1-0.html